# Why is document.documentElement.clientWidth 980px on mobile phone

Tags: responsive-design, viewport

I am trying to understand `documentElement.clientWidth` and `window.innerWidth` and their behavior on various devices. I use this http://67.20.67.232/test.html page to test, one thing perplexing me is that on my Nexus 6 `documentElement.clientWidth` is 980, and I tried it with dev tool's mobile simulation, results are same. So why 980? And, on mobile devices, can `window.innerWidth` be considered the viewport width? The HTML of the page is as follow:

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function loop(){
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                $('#doc').html( document.documentElement.clientWidth );
                $('#win').html( window.innerWidth );
                $('#d1').html($('#w div:eq(0)').width());
                $('#d2').html($('#w div:eq(2)').width());
                loop();
            })
        })();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="w" style="margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;font-size:50px">
            <div style="float:left">client:<span id="doc"></span></div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div style="float:left">window:<span id="win"></span></div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
            <div id="d1"></div>
            <div id="d2"></div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: High resolution phones can pack more pixels per inch, isn't it?

Comment: I just wanna know where this '980' figure comes from

Comment: Probably you might be able to calculate it if you have the phone resolution information and screen dimensions information, or the DPI.

Comment: Ya that is part of what I am seeking. However, on all phones this value is always 980, so I guess it has nothing to do with phone specs

Comment: That might be because you are looking at particular brands of phones only. Take for example a phone that doesn't have full HD resolution and another one that has, etc.

Comment: Also rotate the screen and check...you should get a different value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It's here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW25

"The default width is 980px"

Answer (score 9):

include the viewport meta tag in the head section:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

otherwise most mobile devices will assume it's a desktop site and emulate a larger viewport thats usually 980px.